# Proper way of closing Oracle table update - C# . NET

Tags: c#, oracle

I follow below steps to update an oracle table:

- First calculate observable collection; property indicating a column. Display this information in a WPF datagrid. I save this information to the Oracle database. This seems to work fine.
- While the grid is open, I change the some cell values. I re-saved the modified values to the table. This also works fine.
- I try to get updated/modified values to perform some other calculation. I noticed that my program still used the initially saved values; it didnt pick modified values even though database shows correct values. **Does is happen because I am not committing / closing the Oracle connection properly?**

Here is my code to save the data into Oracle table:

```
using (OracleConnection thisConnection = new OracleConnection(connectionname))
{
    string query = "INSERT INTO TEST(WellBore,PDate, Pressure,Temperature)VALUES(:WellBore,:PDate,:Pressure,:Temperature)";

    OracleCommand myAccessCommand = new OracleCommand(query, thisConnection);

    var sdate = Datetime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString();

    myAccessCommand.Parameters.Add("WellBore", OracleDbType.NVarchar2, 20).Value = “ABC”;
    myAccessCommand.Parameters.Add("PDate", DateTime.Parse(sdate));
    myAccessCommand.Parameters.Add("Pressure", OracleDbType.Decimal).Value = 1000;
    myAccessCommand.Parameters.Add("Temperature ", OracleDbType.Decimal).Value = 50;
    thisConnection.Open();
    myAccessCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    thisConnection.Dispose();
}
```

*So I believe my question how do I commit the connection?*

Comment: Do not call `thisConnection.Dispose()`, it will be disposed anyway when you exit using block

Comment: you need an OracleTransaction, and yes, you need to commit

Comment: Off topic but you might want to remove the extra space in `,: Temperature)` and in `.Add("Temperature ", `

Comment: how do I enter "commit" section here? @tbone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example using an insert statement with a transaction.  It also grabs a returned id value, which may not be needed in your case, but anyway:

```
            int event_id = 0;
            using (OracleConnection oraConn = new OracleConnection(connStr))
            {
                string cmdText = @"insert into EVENT
                    (EVENT_NAME, EVENT_DESC)
                    values
                    (:EVENT_NAME, :EVENT_DESC)
                    RETURNING EVENT_ID INTO :EVENT_ID
                    ";

                using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(cmdText, oraConn))
                {
                    oraConn.Open();
                    OracleTransaction trans = oraConn.BeginTransaction();
                    try
                    {
                        OracleParameter prm = new OracleParameter();
                        cmd.BindByName = true;
                        prm = new OracleParameter("EVENT_NAME", OracleDbType.Varchar2); prm.Value = "SOME NAME"; cmd.Parameters.Add(prm);
                        prm = new OracleParameter("EVENT_DESC", OracleDbType.Varchar2); prm.Value = "SOME DESC"; cmd.Parameters.Add(prm);
                        prm = new OracleParameter("EVENT_ID", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue); cmd.Parameters.Add(prm);

                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        trans.Commit();
                        // return value
                        event_id = ConvertFromDB<int>(cmd.Parameters["EVENT_ID"].Value);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        trans.Rollback();
                        throw;
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        trans.Dispose();
                    }
                    oraConn.Close();
                }
            }
```

Note: The "ConvertFromDB" is just a generic to cast the return value to its .NET equivalent (an int in this case).  Again, if you aren't capturing a returned value, you don't need to worry about it.