# How to return ID after inserting into Oracle

Tags: vb.net, oracle, oledbcommand

This is an example of what I've inherited from what someone else started.  They made some changes to the tables and now column SI_KEY is auto generated when there is an insert into SHOP_INV.  I need that SI_KEY back for later in the form.  Unfortunately I don't know how to do that.  I'm also not sure if I have to put the SI_KEY column in the insert statement if its a column for which I won't supply the value since its now auto generating. I don't think I do so I didn't include it in my example here.  Otherwise it would be before `CATEGORY`.  The code as is works though.

```
STSQL = "insert into SHOP_INV"
STSQL = STSQL & " ("
STSQL = STSQL & "CATEGORY,"
STSQL = STSQL & "MTI_PART_NO,"
STSQL = STSQL & "DESCRIPTION,"
STSQL = STSQL & "CONSUMABLE"
STSQL = STSQL & ") values ("
STSQL = STSQL & "1,"
STSQL = STSQL & "2,"
STSQL = STSQL & "3,"
STSQL = STSQL & "4"
STSQL = STSQL & ")"

MPCS_UPDATE_SQL(UCase(STSQL))
```

Then from the ModModule

```
Public Sub MPCS_UPDATE_SQL(ByVal strSQL As String)
    Dim cmdMPCS As OleDbCommand
    Try

        If OPEN_CONNECTIONS() = False Then
            MessageBox.Show("Error connecting to database.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop)
            Exit Sub
        Else
            cmdMPCS = New OleDbCommand(strSQL, conMPCS)
            cmdMPCS.ExecuteNonQuery()

        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
        Err.Clear()
        Exit Sub
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: you need to use "RETURNING INTO" clause.  Here's an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42673346/proper-way-of-closing-oracle-table-update-c-sharp-net/42675329#42675329) using ODP.net and C#.  Not sure about VB but should be similar.

Comment: How are you auto-generating the key? An identity column in Oracle 12c, a sequence value, a trigger? Also, are you really building queries by string concatenation and not using parameterised queries and bind variables?

Comment: @MT0 I'm not the DB Admin but I was told a trigger.  And no, once I get that working I have a lot more to do, parameters are on my list as there are a ton of these I have to fix.  But I know how to do that, I didn't know how to do this.